# SharePoint 2007 custom theme. where did this CSS file come from?

Tags: sharepoint, themes, stylesheet

We set up the SharePoint 12 hive folder for a custom theme with a new xml entry and folder.

Is everything required for a custom theme living in the theme folder? I'm asking because we are seeing CSS files that appear to be dynamically named rendered on SharePoint pages in the folder that are not actually in the folder.

Will we have to use SPD and custom site changes to get a custom  theme to work?

I've got a designer working only in the theme folder, but he is seeing rendered css that he can't get to. He is not using SPD

That 1011-65001 squence file is found nowhere? what is that an where can I find it. Any way to have my custom theme all hard fixed name css files in that folder without using SPD?

/_themes/MYNEWFOLDER/MYNEWTHEME1011-65001.css?rev=12%2E0%2E0%2E6421

===
Update: I just realzed that css is creatd when I apply the theme and so it's in my _themes site folder. But now, when I attempt to re-apply the theme, that was working before, now i get a write error on _themes.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your first query why its dyanamic name this is because themes which you installed are ghosted version and when you apply them an unghosted version is created for the specific site where it is applied. so a dyanamic naming is required and it cannot be hard coded in MOSS even if you try using SPD you can do it but you have to remove the theming then.
the same you have also have notified in update that the css name is changed only when you apply it.
regarding your second issue of reapplying it did you try applying another them and then back to first one and is giving error then please check the 12 hive logs it will give you cause of failure and if still you are not able to figure out the same plz share the relavent log here  we will try to help you